# Python threading and shutil is not working hand-in-hand?

Tags: python, multithreading, shutil

I'm trying to create a python script that copies files from a remote server to  my local drive. The problem is that I noticed that it doesn't spawn a thread to copy other files in parallel.

```
import shutil
import threading

LocalPath = "C:\\folder1"
RemotePath = "X:\\folder1"

# downloader/copier
def monitorCopy (Filename) :
    print("Copying of "+Filename+" started.")
    shutil.copy(RemotePath+"\\"+Filename+"\\"+Filename+".zip",LocalPath)
    print("Copying of "+Filename+" finished.")

# main function
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    filelist = ["file1","file2","file3"]
    print(range(len(filelist)))
    p = []
    for i in range(len(filelist)) :
        p.append(i)
        p[i] = threading.Thread(target=monitorCopy,args=(filelist[i],))
        p[i].daemon = True
        p[i].start()
        p[i].join()
```

Folders tree looks like this:

```
Remote Repository
     [+] --- Filename
                [+] --- Filename.zip

Local Repository
     [+] --- Filename.zip
```

can someone please help me on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're calling `join` on each thread object right after you create it, which is preventing more than one thread from running at a time. A `thread_object.join()` call tells Python to block until `thread_object` has completed execution, which in your case means you're starting one thread for an item in `filelist`, blocking until the thread finishes, then moving on to the next item in `filelist` and doing the same thing. What you really want to do is create all your threads in parallel, and only `join` them after they're all created:

```
if __name__ == "__main__" :
    filelist = ["file1","file2","file3"]
    print(range(len(filelist)))
    p = []
    for f in filelist:
        t = threading.Thread(target=monitorCopy,args=(f,))
        p.append(t)
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

    for t in p:
        t.join()
```

Comment: I see. It works. I have one more question, if a thread's task ends, does it automatically take itself out of the list?

Comment: @user3814548 No, the completed `Thread` object will remain in the list.

Comment: hmmmm. Do you have any suggestion on how to do this? I'm thinking of having "t" to become global and pass "f" to monitorCopy and just add t[f].stop().

Comment: @user3814548 Can you explain a bit about your motivation for deleting the thread objects from the list? If you're calling `thread.join()` on each thread in the list, once you're done, every thread will be finished, and the whole list can just be thrown away; there's no reason to bother deleting individual entries.

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't know about that. I'm new to python programming. My motivation is that the in the future I will replace the filelist into a dynamic list which parses a text file which contains filenames. So when the main function parses the text file and finds a new filename from it, it will create a thread to download it. The code up there is for python practice.

Comment: @user3814548 Hmm, even then, I think the same principle can still be applied. The only difference is that instead of using `filelist` as a source to populate the `p` list, a text file will be used. You can still simply `start` each thread until you're done parsing the text file, and then `join` them all when you're done. If you're worried about having too many thread objects created at once (which is a valid concern), you can use a `multiprocessing.pool.ThreadPool` to limit the number of threads that run concurrently.

Comment: I see, thank you. This is a big help for my project.